# vscode-go input tabs of size 4 instead 8

Tags: go, visual-studio-code, gofmt

I have `Visual Studio Code Insiders` installed. Basically I've installed `Go` extension from Microsoft and written simple hello world app. Now I always use spaces to indent my code, but I saw that it changed to tabs of size 4. So I thought: yay, what a nice extension, now I can start to write my code.

Then I remembered, that the default code indent from `gofmt` should be 8 as tabs. And I checked. `gofmt main.go` indeed outputs my code with tabs of size 8. But vscode keeps doing tabs of size 4. I thought maybe it doesn't even call `gofmt` but when I go RPM->Format document with - it actually does. But still, tabs of size 4. What am I doing wrong in this scenario?

```
    "editor.renderWhitespace": "all",
    "editor.fontFamily": "Hack",
    "editor.fontSize": 12,
    "editor.minimap.enabled": false,
    "editor.fontLigatures": true,
    "workbench.editor.enablePreview": false,
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "editor.formatOnPaste": true,
    "editor.cursorSmoothCaretAnimation": true,
    "editor.detectIndentation": false
```

Those my only editor settings and I dont have any custom settings regarding `Go` extension

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`go fmt` uses tab characters ("`\t`") to indent the beginning of a line. How a tab is displayed (tab width) is up to your text editor or IDE. I have Tab Width set to 4 in my text editors. My terminal program uses a tab width of 8.

For example, for xed,

> Editor Preferences
>
> Tabs
>
> Use the Tab width spin box to specify the width of the space that xed
>   inserts when you press the Tab key.
>
> Select the Insert spaces instead of tabs option to specify that xed
>   inserts spaces instead of a tab character when you press the Tab key.

Comment: So basically everything is fine? I meet like the code guidelines? It's just how my editor renders the tab character, right? I also got Tab Width set to 4

Comment: If you or your IDE runs `go fmt` on your code, everything will be fine.